# User cannot RSS with IE

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer

One of my users cannot work with RSS feeds. The problem was originally noticed with Outlook (where we get error 0x800C0008), but we can reproduce the problem with Internet Explorer

- Calling any RSS feed URL in IE results in "The download of this feed was interrupted". We even created a dummy rss feed on a http web server in our LAN to exclude proxy or https-certificate problems - no change
- Other users (including newly created users) do not have the problem on the same machine (we are working with RDP)
- Resetting IE to default settings: The problem persists
- Deleting the roaming profile and having the problem user start with a fresh profile: The problem persists
- Making the user a Domain Administrator: Problem solved

Of course, making the user a domain admin is not an option. What can be the cause of the described behaviour? Per the experiment with a fresh profile, it cannot be personal settings; per the test as administrator, it cannot really be an interrupted connection (as the error message tries to suggest).

Comment: I would look into what is the difference between this user and other users. Is there some logon script, software settings, software installations etc.

My guess is there is some application messing up registry settings for  the "application/rss+xml" mime type. This  application is trying to perform something that requires admin privileges and crashes because no permission.

Comment: @MrZach There is the same logon skript for everybody. What kind of software settings, software installations etc. could survive profile deletion? I found no user changes to the application/rss+xml mime type (whcih, again, would have been in the user profile) ...

Comment: This can survive with domain policies/GPO'es

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have a Windows Server 2008 R2 tag with the question, are you doing this on a Windows Server? If so, you can try to turn off the IE Enhanced Security for administrators and users and see if it helps. Here is a [HowTo](http://www.dell.com/support/article/sg/en/sgdhs1/sln150222/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-ie-esc-on-windows-server-2008-2008-r2?lang=en)

Other options to try are to put the URL of the RSS feed into either **Local Intranet** or **Trusted Sites** zone, and see if that helps. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/815141/internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-changes-the-browsing) are details.

Comment: The server is used as RDP-Host all the time. Accordingly, the IE settings are already more user-friendly.

Comment: In this case, the only thing I can think of is the permission this user has on the that server. I guess it doesn't require domain admin. If you grant this user local admin on that server, it would also work. Can you compare if this user has the same permission with other users?